# I want to track keyboard usage telling me which keys I press (not which characters I type)

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation

I want to track keyboard usage. More specifically, I want to check how much I really use the numpad. I am looking for a solution that:

- runs in the background
- differentiates between numpad and numeric keys on main keyboard
- let's me copy the logs / see the logs so I can generate a summary myself or maybe gives a summary of the key presses itself

Note that common keyloggers can't be used as they don't differentiate between the two. Karabiner-Elements Event Viewer shows these key presses (and mouse button presses) but only the last 10 or so.

Comment: You're looking for a keylogger software then?

Comment: @Thinkr If a keylogger can differentiate between numpad keys and the numbers on the main/alphabetic keyboard, then sure.

Comment: Well a classic keylogger will give you the list of the the keys you've pressed on your keyboard and the website or app you were on when you pressed those keys. BUT being able to download that list depends on the keylogger you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a product called [WhatPulse](https://whatpulse.org/premium#compare) that appears to fit what you’re looking for.  They offer both a free and a premium version; the free version seems to have what you’re looking for:

- Count Keys & Clicks
- History of Keys & Clicks per Day
- Keyboard & Mouse Heat Maps
- Per Application Keys & Clicks

There’s also an online dashboard and several reports including “heatmaps” of what keys you press.  Some of the better reports are, obviously, only available with a premium subscription.  However, this seems to be an excellent product for what you’re looking for.